# Http 404 Spring java config

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, web, configuration

Hello i have problem with java config in spring. I was trying to complete it by learning from mutliple tutorials but still i have something wrong. Any clue ?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vozcc.png)

AppConfig.java

```
package org.spring.mvc.libraryDemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

/**
 * Created by wiktor on 28.12.2015.
 */
@Configuration //adnotacja oznaczajaca plik konfiguracyjny
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.spring.mvc.libraryDemo") //enable skan komponentow
@Import({AppConfig.class}) //na co musi jeszcze uwazac Spring
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

SpringConfigInit

```
package org.spring.mvc.libraryDemo.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringConfigInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Controller

```
package org.spring.mvc.libraryDemo.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Created by wiktor on 28.12.2015.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap modelMap)
    {
        modelMap.addAttribute("greeting","witaj");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this type of servlet mapping, I think you will find your app at http://localhost:8080/{warfile name}/, not at http://localhost:8080/

Comment: by warfile name I meant the following:  If your warfile name is MyApp.war, the url should be http://localhost:8080/MyApp/ .  There must be a trailing forward slash after MyApp (which Stack Overflow is omitting). Is that what you tried?

Comment: yep but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two approaches here (as seen is your web.xml):

ContextLoaderListener with /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml : this means that your spring application will be configured by the xml stuff in applicationContext.xml.

But obviously you want to use the Java Config, that is the beans defined under @Configuration annotated classes. To enable this, one way is to change your web xml for something like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>SpringRootConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext is the key here. That will scan your classpath and take the @Configuration stuff into account.

Comment: tried something like this but the same :d with your try i have error between init-param.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>org.spring.mvc.libraryDemo.config.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```